# Authorizing client browser

Tags: asp.net

I am writing an app that will be used for a kiosk. The app will be asp.net, I will only want the app accessible from certain computers, using chrome.

I don't think limiting by up address would work since a few of the computers will be taken to conventions and used there.

I was thinking something with a custom certificate but would like advice.

Comment: You want to lock it to hardware? A mac address could be more reliable, but it's easily 'spoofed'. If it's an ASP app then it needs a web server to actually function so you're better off securing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to give login or/and password/special key to allow them to login through an identification page. After that, you put cookie into their chrome.

Finally, like all websites.